# Position: absolute not respecting parent element in IE6

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

I have a page with a `div` in it.

The `div` contains an image, is 700px wide and 300px tall. It is set to `position: relative`.

To show some text to the bottom of the DIV, I put a `span` into it and give it `position: absolute; bottom: 8px`

This works fine in all browsers, except IE6. IE6 puts the text *to the very bottom of the page*.

It is as if the parent element with its `position: relative` doesn' t even exist.

Is this known IE6 behaviour, or am I overlooking something?

I just checked, the HTML code passes W3C validation.

Comment: just a hunch, can you apply the float: and clear: properties, looks like a clearfix issue

Comment: Cheers @questzen, you're right, it needed Layout, I worked around it with `zoom: 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you set a height to your div? If there is no height set, IE6 considers this element as non existent.

Comment: Not explicitly, no. Could this have to do with having layout? I'll try a `zoom: 1` hang on.

Comment: Cheers for getting me on the right track, a `zoom: 1` did it. (I can't set an explicit height.)

Answer (score 2):

I would say, use the

```
height:auto!important;
height:1px;
```

trick that will validate as well, and also give layout to IE6 which does not support the `!important` directive..